# Controlling Coordinates of Rectangle in Image Inclusion

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, includegraphics

I'm working on a document where I want to include images with the option to draw a rectangle on them. I've created a command `\includegraphicsWithOptionalRectangle` that takes two arguments: the path to the image file and an optional argument specifying whether to draw a rectangle or not. If the optional argument is set to `Rect`, a red rectangle is drawn on the image.

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\includegraphicsWithOptionalRectangle}[2][noRect]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#2}};
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Rect}}
                {
                    % Define rectangle coordinates
                    \coordinate (lowerleft) at (0.72,0.89); % Adjust these coordinates as needed
                    \coordinate (upperright) at (0.55,0.75); % Adjust these coordinates as needed
                    % Draw rectangle
                    \draw[red] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
                }
                {
                    % Draw no rectangle
                }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    
    % Image with no Rectangle (default):
    \includegraphicsWithOptionalRectangle{example-image}
    
    % Image with Rectangle (controlled coordinates):
    \includegraphicsWithOptionalRectangle[Rect]{example-image}
    
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**QUESTION**

How can I control the coordinates of the `lowerleft` and `upperright` corners of the rectangle when the optional argument is set to `Rect`? I want to be able to specify these coordinates dynamically, depending on the image and the desired placement of the rectangle. Any suggestions or improvements to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by `xparse`. Define star version of `\myincludegraphics` as default `includegraphics` without rectangle drawing. Then the non-star version will have two optional args to specify the coordinates of the rectangle. First one will be the lower left corner location in fraction of the total width and height. The second one will be upper right corner location in fraction of the total width and height. Here 1 will be the full width and height, by default the rectangle will be drawn for the full image. Here is the code and examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myincludegraphics}{s O{0,0} O{1,1} m}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#4}%
}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#4}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
\draw[red] (#2) rectangle (#3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}
\myincludegraphics*{example-image}
\myincludegraphics{example-image}
\myincludegraphics[0.25,0.35][0.75,0.65]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well Done!

Comment: Can you maybe help with this question (since it is based on your answer here)? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709356/278762