# Controlling Label Text in TikZ Nodes with \NewDocumentCommand: Including or Excluding Descriptions

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am working on a document where I include images using TikZ nodes. I have a command `\myincludegraphics` that includes an image along with a rectangle and a label node. However, I am struggling to control the text of the label node. Specifically, I want to have the option to include or exclude the label text when using the command. How can I achieve this functionality? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Note that I need the following possibilities:**

image **without** `rectangle`-Node and **without** `label`-Node:

> `\myincludegraphics*{example-image}`

image **with default** `rectangle`-Node and **without** `label`-Node:

> `\myincludegraphics{example-image}`

image **with specific** `rectangle`-Node and **without** `label`-Node:

> `\myincludegraphics[0.25,0.35][0.75,0.65]{example-image}`

image **without** `rectangle`-Node and **with default** `label`-Node:

> `\myincludegraphics[ShowDefaultLabel]{example-image}`

image **with specific** `rectangle`-Node and **with default** `label`-Node:

> `\myincludegraphics[0.25,0.35][0.75,0.65][ShowDefaultLabel]{example-image}`

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myincludegraphics}{s O{0,0} O{1,1} m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#4}%
    }{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#4}};
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                \node[anchor=center, red] (label) at (0.5,0.9) {my image description};%
                \draw[red] (#2) rectangle (#3);
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}
    \myincludegraphics*{example-image}
    \myincludegraphics{example-image}
    \myincludegraphics[0.25,0.35][0.75,0.65]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Is your description always a fixed text? I don't think so.

Comment: the description text is always fix for my propose

Comment: I think that using key/value argumens like [in this @egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669975/38080) will lead to a better interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a optional token like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myincludegraphics}{s O{0,0} O{1,1} t\displaytitle m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#5}%
    }{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#5}};
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                \IfBooleanT{#4}{\node[anchor=center, red] (label) at (0.5,0.9) {my image description};}%
                \draw[red] (#2) rectangle (#3);
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}
    \myincludegraphics*{example-image}
    \myincludegraphics{example-image}
    \myincludegraphics[0.25,0.35][0.75,0.65]\displaytitle{example-image}
\end{document}
```

If you want to use the optional arg, you could do this (in this way, you could define the title using #4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myincludegraphics}{s O{0,0} O{1,1} d<> m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#5}};
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                \IfValueT{#4}{\node[anchor=center, red] (label) at (0.5,0.9) {#4};}%
                \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%%
    }{%
        \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{#5}};
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                \IfValueT{#4}{\node[anchor=center, red] (label) at (0.5,0.9) {#4};}%
                \draw[red] (#2) rectangle (#3);
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}
    \myincludegraphics*<A title>{example-image}
    \myincludegraphics{example-image}
    \myincludegraphics[0.25,0.35][0.75,0.65]<anything like a title>{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey thanks Tom, is there way to do it with your option O? I found this solution very elegant. For instance: O{showLabel}

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer I don't think it is ideal when using `O{showLabel}`, because you will be forced to input the second and third option args, if you want to change the third one to something else. Unless you define the third optional arg with some different delimiters such as using `d<>`. Then, judge the if optional arg have a value by `IfValueT{<arg#>}{<code>}`.  But you essentially just need to type empty <> in order to include the title.  I will include an example in the answer.

Comment: hello tom, i edited my question. i added all the possibilities i would like to use. could you provide a code for this? Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer I think my second method could meet all your requirements.

Comment: ah sorry i did not see :) let me check. i give you feedback as soon as possible

Comment: Hello Tom: works fine (I used your second method): `{RectangleNode: no, LabelNode: no}`; `{RectangleNode: yes-default, LabelNode: no}`; `{RectangleNode: yes-specific, LabelNode: yes-specific}`; `{RectangleNode: yes-default, LabelNode: yes-specific}`. Now only the case `{RectangleNode: no, LabelNode: yes-specific}` is missing. Could you provide code also including the last case?

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer Updated